# My 1 year old daughter suddenly stopped eating food

Tags: food, eating, milk

My daughter ate about everything we gave her, in different quantities depending on how she finds the taste. But suddenly, one fine nite, she woke up, vomited nothing but some cough, and next day on, she ate nothing at all, means nothing at all. All the solids, semi solid foods she ate with ease and taste, she spits out as soon as we keep in her mouth( whenever we can manage that) 
We have tried so many tastes, dishes and recipes, she is not ready to eat anything, she spits out everything with her tongue out.

All she has is Milk, throughout the day. She is basically hungry all  the time. 
I dont know what to do. 
Doctors say change the taste but she takes in nothing, tried everything.  Please suggest

Comment: Maybe she has some pain in her mouth, tongue or throat. How long has this been going on?

Answer (score 3):

She should be coming up on her 15 month visit in a few. See if she has fallen off her growth curve at that visit. You'll probably be surprised that she will not have done so.

In the meantime, lots of kids show variability in their eating. Keep offering her baby foods (try some fruits), cereals, or pureed table foods (introduce with care; she's still young). She won't starve. If you're breastfeeding and are worried she isn't getting enough milk, you can supplement with a bottle of formula.

If she acts like she's in any distress, call your doctor.